# VideoJS - Chapters don't work?

Tags: video.js

I've got VideoJS working beautifully, except for the chapters function.

I'm just using the `demo.html` that came with the JS package. Edited it to include my mp4, and subtitle and chapter VTT files.

Subtitles work great, but when I set the chapter track to `default="default"` (as is necessary to enable it), the video control bar disappears.

Suggestions?

[Working subtitles page](http://wc.acbaldwin.info/js/video-js/demo-subtitles.html)

[Broken chapters page](http://wc.acbaldwin.info/js/video-js/demo-chapters.html)

My VTT syntax seems to be correct:

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:00 --> 00:00:22
Chapter 1

2
00:00:22 --> 00:00:30
Short chapter

3
00:00:30 --> 00:00:45
Finale
```

I've seen a few folks with the same issue in the last month, all unresolved.

One post from July 2012 has chapters working - if anyone has a link to the old VideoJS version that may have been used at that time, I'd love to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chapters support isn't available in Video.js 4 [quite yet](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/676) (hopefully soon!), but you can still use version 3.2 from the CDN.

[video.js](http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js)

[video-js.css](http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css)

Be aware that Video.js 3.2 is unsupported at this point.

Comment: Just realized I haven't revisited this issue - thanks for your answer!

Comment: Your welcome! If it helped, please mark it as the answer (gotta get those fake internet points) :)